# Change display name of unit tests in JUnit Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible for an Eclipse plugin to change the display name of unit tests run by the default Eclipse JUnit plugin?

Some background: I'm trying to create a plugin which will display unit test names (in the JUnit view in Eclipse) a bit different from the actual method name. If the actual test method name is "anEmptyCollectionHasSizeZero" I want it to be displayed in the Eclipse JUnit view as "An empty collection has size zero".

I've managed to display the test method names in the way described above as a separate view in a plugin, but would as I said like to get this feature integrated in the normal JUnit view. I tried to see if I could find a related extension point, but could not find anything. Is it possible to do this?

Also, is there a plugin which already does this, or similar?

Comment: any news? I would really like such a feature as well. Is your current attempt (in a separate view) released in any format? Thanks.

Comment: @Ittai: No news I'm afraid. A very early version of the Eclipse plugin is available on http://storyteller.socosomi.com/. It is very primitive yet, however. Still under development and not really meant to be released yet. But feel free to take a look if you want to. :-)

Comment: I'm also interested in this :)

Comment: I found this book about eclipse plugins http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321205758 . Hopefully, the code samples can be downloaded, and at first look in the `circle-2` source part, they achieve to add listeners to the test runs, and specifically on the `LabelProvider` (see `TestReportLabelProvider.java`), maybe you can take some inspiration from it. My 2 cents ;-).

Comment: @Ittai, Alex: Just wanted to tell you that a public version of the Eclipse plugin I talked about has been released. It still does not change the display names of unit tests as they run, but it gives you a separate Related Tests view that show you relevant tests side-by-side with the code you are writing. http://storyteller.socosomi.com/

Comment: @henko Thanks for the heads up, will take a look.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the exact answer, but the best place to start is likely by looking at the code for `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.ui.TestRunnerViewPart` (in the plug-in `org.eclipse.jdt.junit`). That `ViewPart` is the JUnit view that you see in Eclipse.

It looks like `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.model.TestCaseElement.getTestMethodName()` might be the place where the name is obtained from. Maybe you can trace how/when those elements are created and inject some other name. It looks like the implementation class is internal though (`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.model.TestElement`), so you might be out of luck.

I'd suggest asking on the [JDT forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/13/276902598fcd6ab3a8b515369e652c79/) about the possibility of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

There don't seem to be any plugable way to change the label or the colors used.

(I had hoped the label provider used for the `TestViewer` was based on a `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDecoratorManager().getLabelDecorator()` so the image, label and color could be decorated, but that does not seem to be the case...)

Comment: BTW, if you want this to change, file a new bug on Bugzilla: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the [jnario](http://jnario.org/#home) sources. They have implemented something like that, where the JUnit window displays something that is surely not a stack frame.

[image]

Comment: I've looked around a bit. It is quite complex however, but seem promising. With a bit of bad luck, it might be the case that they can do it because they implement their own type of document (through XText) rather than using Java files, but we'll see!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the setName() method of the class junit.framework.TestCase (or the constructor with the name parameter).

```
public MyTestCase() {
    super("This is my JUnit test");
```

By default a TestCase defines the methods to be executed by it's name, which we have just overwritten. To make it runnable we have to overwrite the run method like this.

```
@Override
protected void runTest() throws Throwable {
    testMyTest();
}
```